# Can I turn this active sentence to passive?

Tags: grammar

Can I turn this active sentence to passive: "I have a cow"

If not then, what is the explanation of it?

Comment: **A cow is had by me.** -- at least technically, that would be the passive voice version of your original sentence.

Comment: I'm sure somewhere in our Help Guide there's something about questions needing to reflect *real-world issues*, but I can't find it just now. I can think of no possible reason why anyone (native speaker or learner) would want to recast *I have a cow* in passive voice, so it seems to me this is a "non-question".

Comment: This [page](http://folk.uio.no/hhasselg/grammar/Week11_word_order.htm) explains it nicely. To be passivised, the verb has to be dynamic, not stative.

Answer (score 2):

A verb may describe an action "I ate the cheeseburger" Or a state "I have a cheeseburger"

The first may be expressed as "The cheeseburger was eaten (by me)" but a verb that describes a state should not be put into a passive voice. So "A cheeseburger is had" is not good English.

See more examples at [English word order](http://folk.uio.no/hhasselg/grammar/Week11_word_order.htm)